# Find whether the value has been updated or inserted in Dynamodb?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am using updatedItem() function which is either inserting or updating values in Dynamodb. If values are updating I want to fetch those items and invoke a new lambda function. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct approach would be to add `ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW'` to the params you use for you `updateItem()` call.

You can then tell if you're inserted a new item because the returned `Attributes` will include your partition (and sort, if you've used a composite) key.

This is because you cannot change the key of an item, so if all you've done is update an item, then you would not have updated its key. But if you have *created* a new item, then you would have 'updated' its key.

However, if you want to react to items being updated in a dynamo table, you could alternatively use DynamoDB Streams [(docs)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html).

These streams allow you to trigger lambdas on the transactions on the dynamo table. This lambda could then filter the events for updates and react accordingly. The advantage of this architectural approach is it means your 'onUpdate' functionality will trigger if *anything* updates the table- not just the specific lambda.

Comment: How would you go about detecting updates or new item in `dynamodb streams`?
I still cannot figure it out

Answer (score 2):

Don't think previously accepted answer works.  The return Attributes never returned the partition/sort keys, whether an item was updated or created.

What worked for me was to add `ReturnValues: UPDATED_OLD`.  If the returned Attributes is undefined, then you know that an item was created.